# How to replace the entire code of main branch with code of some other branch

Tags: git, github

My code has some bugs on the main branch, but I have the corrected code on some other branch. I don't know how to replace the code on the main branch with that one.

Comment: Do you want to rewrite the history so that the main branch does not have the bug anymore or do you want to create a new commit in the main branch that fixes the bug?

Comment: A question _just like this one_ was asked a couple of hours ago. I wonder how many variations of the same question have been around here since it started. Try: `git checkout the-other-branch -- .` or `git restore --worktree --staged --source=the-other-branch -- .`. This does _not_ mess up with history... only bringing over _contents_ of what's in the other branch.